# How do I get the program name in Racket?

Tags: racket

I would like to programmatically detect the program name within Racket code. This can be done in Chicken Scheme with:

```
#!/bin/sh
#|
exec csi -ss $0 ${1+"$@"}
exit
|#

(define (main)
    (display (format "Program: ~a\n" (program-name)))
    (exit))

(if (not (equal? (program-name) "csi"))
    (main))
```

How could I emulate this in Racket?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
(find-system-path 'run-file)
```

See also `racket/cmdline` for how to parse the commandline.

http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Command-Line_Parsing.html

Answer (score 3):

Note: for this particular pattern of execution, to have a library module that can also be run as a main, use a [submodule](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Module_Syntax.html#%28tech._submodule%29) named **main**.  See [Main and Test Submodules](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Module_Syntax.html#%28part._main-and-test%29), which shows how to do this.